# Offline check a token's validity against user alteration

Tags: validation, encryption, access-token

I have a question about protecting data against an untrusted end-user in the following scenario:

**Basic feature to implement:**

1. User logs into desktop app using username and password in order to have access to a subscription based software
2. The server respond with an encrypted token having a validity (30 days for example) and a Hardware Identifier specific for that one machine for which the user is now entitled. The server also responds with a public key with which the token above can be decrypted/checked
3. Every time the user launch the desktop app, if we are in an offline scenario we check the validity of the token by decrypting it with the public key, and then we can check if it is still within the validity period, and if it is on the correct Hardware as well (i.e. if the user did not just copy the encrypted files on a different machine and try to use the same account on more computers simultaneously)

**Problem:**
The scenario above has no protection against an untrusted user.

**Example of possible attack:**

1. The user decrypts the token using the public key
2. He now edits the token and sets a new Hardware Identifier, for the new machine he wants to copy the tokens
3. He edits the expiring date to 31.12.2099 for example
4. He generates his own private-public pair of keys
5. He encrypt the token again with his own private key
6. Now he can transport the encrypted token together with his own public key on the new machine, and as soon as he launches the desktop app in an offline scenario, the app has no way to tell that the token has been altered. It checks the authenticity of the token, but it can't check that the public key has been corrupted as well.

Every asymmetric encryption approach assumes that the end-user is trustable. For example when signing an app with a certificate, we assume that the user has no intention in attacking the offline trusted root certificates.

**A solution I avoid** would be to encrypt the private key or the public key within the code, but:

1. That is very very unsafe
2. That is not flexible in case you want to update the keys
3. It can be reversed engineered

After studying cryptography for a while I never realized that this scenario is so unsafe. Now I am wondering how a lot of already existing apps work in this scenario without exposing themselves to this so easy attack?

Thank you!

Comment: The point of using a public key is that no random person can just generate their own token that can be decrypted by that key, only your server holds the private key. To prevent them to change the public key used by your app, embed it in the code, sign your binary, and on launch verify the signature is valid. Obfuscators may help prevent attackers from trying to patch your assembly verification logic but at some point, you'd need to ask yourself if the effort and potential annoyance to legitimate users is worth the deterrent.

Comment: That answered my question entirely. Thank you very much!